# stop using some auto css

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SCSS in my _layout.scss file

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and this SCSS is auto replaced with following css, but i want to stop using `(display: -webkit-box;)`

```
.wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

i mean to say the css should be as seen below

```
.wrap {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your autoprefixer. I assume you use Gulp or Grunt?

You can also use this workaround:

```
var postcss = require('postcss');

module.exports = postcss.plugin('flexbox-cleaner', function () {
    return function (css) {
        css.walkAtRules('supports', function (rule) {
            rule.params = rule.params.replace('((display: -webkit-flex) or (display: -ms-flexbox) or (display: flex))', '(display: flex)');
        });
    };
}
```

this is a postCSS plugin and it let autoproefixer ignore some flexbox parameters (like yours).

[source](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer/issues/107)